# Elgato Eve is connected on Home app of iPhone but not on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, homekit

I have Elgato Eve Thermo. Home app on iPhone shows that the device is connected. While on iPad, Home app shows that the device is not connected.

Any ideas what is going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the iPad should have Bluetooth enabled. I hope at least that some kind of info or hint is displayed.